# Complex MySQL query on many-to-many for specific schema

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have searched and gone through the available topics similar to mine. But, failed to find that satisfies my requirements. Hence, posting it here.

I have four tables as follows:

```
"Organization" table:
--------------------------------
| org_id       | org_name      |
| 1            | A             |
| 2            | B             |
| 3            | C             |

"Members" table:
----------------------------------------------
| mem_id       | mem_name     | org_id       |
| 1            | mem1         | 1            |
| 2            | mem2         | 1            |
| 3            | mem3         | 2            |
| 4            | mem4         | 3            |

"Resource" table:
--------------------------------
| res_id       | res_name      |
| 1            | resource1     |
| 2            | resource2     |
| 3            | resource3     |
| 4            | resource4     |

"member-resource" table:
--------------------------------------------
| sl_no        | mem_id     | res_id       |
| 1            | 1          | 1            |
| 2            | 1          | 2            |
| 3            | 2          | 1            |
| 4            | 4          | 3            |
| 5            | 3          | 4            |
| 6            | 2          | 3            |
| 7            | 4          | 3            |
```

I want to find out the total number of shared resources according to organizations. Expected output is as follows:

```
| org_name       | Shared Resources     |
| A              | 1                    |
| B              | 0                    |
| C              | 1                    |
```

I also want to find out the total number of duplicate resources according to organizations. Expected output is as follows:

```
| org_name       | Duplicate Resources  |
| A              | 2                    |
| B              | 0                    |
| C              | 1                    |
```

Any help in this regard will highly be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Can you explain how duplicates are calculated in posted output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the total number of shared resources across organizations you can try

```
SELECT o.org_name, COALESCE(q.total, 0) shared_resources
  FROM organization o LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT m.org_id, COUNT(DISTINCT mr.res_id) total
    FROM member_resource mr JOIN members m
      ON mr.mem_id = m.mem_id
   WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT *
      FROM member_resource mr2 JOIN members m2
        ON mr2.mem_id = m2.mem_id
     WHERE mr2.res_id = mr.res_id
       AND m2.org_id <> m.org_id
  )
   GROUP BY org_id
) q
     ON o.org_id = q.org_id
```

Sample output:

```
| ORG_NAME | SHARED_RESOURCES |
|----------|------------------|
|        A |                1 |
|        B |                0 |
|        C |                1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be373/21)** demo

---

To get the total number of duplicate resources across organizations you can try

```
SELECT o.org_name, COALESCE(q.total, 0) duplicate_resources
  FROM organization o LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT m.org_id, COUNT(DISTINCT mr.res_id) total
    FROM member_resource mr JOIN members m
      ON mr.mem_id = m.mem_id
   WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT *
      FROM member_resource mr2
     WHERE mr2.res_id = mr.res_id
       AND mr2.sl_no <> mr.sl_no
  )
   GROUP BY org_id
) q
     ON o.org_id = q.org_id
```

Sample output:

```
| ORG_NAME | DUPLICATE_RESOURCES |
|----------|---------------------|
|        A |                   2 |
|        B |                   0 |
|        C |                   1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be373/34)** demo

Comment: What about the duplicate resources??

Comment: See updated answer. Unfortunately you didn't answer my question in comments explaining how it should be calculated, so I did my best to deduce what you meant by that.

Comment: > Sorry brother. Just now saw your comments. For your info, any resource is identified as duplicated if it occurs in more than one rows irrespective of organization. Can you please check if your SQL still works perfect in this case. The first one works perfect.